# Example to override phtml files from my custom theme

Tags: magento2

I need to override the phtml template using my custom theme.

1) I need to override the toolbar.phtml from Catalog module
except that i need to use my toolbar.phtml which is placed in my custom theme.

2) If we use this method, is there a need to use the layout xml files?
If so how to override the same.

Need example for both!

Comment: Do you try  read official documentation http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html?

Comment: I followed the official doc...But im stuck in this issue as to why results of products are not rendering... http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133188/issue-in-overriding-core-phtml-files-in-custom-theme-magento2

Answer (score 2):

You only need to use one method.

**1. Override template file**

Copy the file from:
`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml`

To your theme: `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml`

Make your changes in the new file.

**2. Load new template file via xml**

As an example using the category view:

Extend the parent `catalog_category_view.xml` file by creating: `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

In the body section update the template of the `product_list_toolbar` block with:

`<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Theme::html/new-toolbar.phtml"/>`

The example path of the template file corresponds to: `app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/templates/html/new-toolbar.phtml`

Comment: Hi Oscarpas, do you mean , vendor/magento as app/code/Magento/Catalog/... cause i dont have vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/ ..I have installed Magento using composer github...I have vendor/magento/composer

Comment: If its not in `vendor/Magento` it should be in `app/design/frontend/Magento`. You can turn on template hints to make sure.

Comment: Ok for eg i f i want to get the pagination in my products page from my custom theme..can u pls show an eg for the same?

Comment: Turn on template hints to find the correct .phtml file. Use the instructions in my answer.

Comment: Hi @Oscarpas, could you please help me in this error for overriding my custom layout file.. I have followed the same step as mentioned ...http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133188/issue-in-overriding-core-phtml-files-in-custom-theme-magento2