# How to override the file name.phtml in my custom module: Magento-2

Tags: php, magento-2.1.7

```
Vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\widget\name.phtml
```

override into my custom module

```
mycompany\custommodule\view\frontend\templates\widget\name.phtml
```

but I can't override this phtml file . If any one knows, help me?

Comment: Try creating your custom theme and simply copy the file to your theme folder.  Check the following link,  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132177/example-to-override-phtml-files-from-my-custom-theme

Comment: this file is not setting from layout file. you need to override block Magento\Customer\Block\Widget

Comment: how to override block and if there is need any layout file?

Comment: you can achieve with plugin or preference

Comment: i want preference method to override this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to override `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml` file

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name">
        <plugin name="custom_widget_name" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\Block\Widget\Name" />
    </type>

</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Customer/Block/Widget/Name.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Customer\Block\Widget;
class Name
{
    public function after_construct(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Name $result)
    {

        $result->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::widget/name.phtml');
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

Now copy `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml` and paste into `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml`

Comment: Please explain overiding  in preference method(without using plugin)

Comment: Plugin is better than preference. Why do you want to override with preference method?

Comment: ok.i want to override \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository .. for hide lastname validation.

Comment: Did you know about this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/255630/magento-2-call-custom-phtml-file-in-product-page-using-plugin